# Do something after user login in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to update user information in database after user's login.I searched hook for that but can't find.What should i do now?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

The action hook wp_login runs when the user logs in - it can run a simple function.

```
function do_anything() {
    //do stuff
}
add_action('wp_login', 'do_anything');
```

[Citation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28522/is-there-a-hook-that-runs-after-a-user-logs-in)